# How to reduce large icon spacing in file browser for Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, icons

I've Win 10 Pro (10.0.16299) on my laptop and noticed two unusual things:

First, in a file browser window of any program, when viewing options is set to **medium**, **large** or **extra large** icons, the icons appear with a huge amount of vertical and horizontal spacing (although slightly less dramatic for horizontal) in relation to each other.

In addition to this, in ALL explorer windows, the actual size of icons or thumbnails does not change between "**Large**" and "**Extra large**" viewing modes. it only adds to the spacing.

I'm wondering if something has gone wrong which causes this behavior.

I'm on a 3840x2160 pixels resolution if that matters.

[image: Screenshot for reference]

Appreciate any hints on this.

Comment: I suspect it's caused by the length of the file names. Try renaming or temporarily moving to another directory and see if the icon spacing changes. I generally use Details view, so long names aren't a problem. I have also set icon spacing on my desktop with [Winaero Tweaker](https://winaero.com/request.php?1796) - this is the down-load link, which is difficult to find amid the promoted software, though the program itself works well and is ad-free. I don't know if this affects application dialogues, but it may be worth trying. You can copy the files without installing and run it portably.

Comment: Does Ctrl-mouse scroll wheel help, or does it just change icon *size* rather than *spacing*?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks for commenting. Ctrl+wheel is just changing the icon size while keeping the same large spacing.

Comment: @AFH Thanks for the hint. I have to use the large icon view cause the folder contains  images that I need to choose very often. I checked the filenames and they're not really long ones, at most 15 chars and they used to be wrapped before. I also used the Winaero Tweaker tool and change icon spacing, but it only affects desktop icons and not Explorer windows.

Comment: I got the same problem with 3840x2160 pixels resolution.

Comment: was this ever solved? I am having the same issue. Huge amount of explorer real estate being wasted.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+mouse scroll wheel down to minimum size and then up to maximum size helps me to reduce the space.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/946635)

Comment: @Burgi: It looks like an answer to me.  It [has been suggested before](https://superuser.com/q/1314775/150988#comment1957021_1314775), and the OP [said that it does not work](https://superuser.com/q/1314775/150988#comment1958099_1314775); i.e., it is *a wrong answer.*  But an orange dog is still a dog, and a wrong answer is still an answer.

Comment: I wrote this answer again with a little more information. Scroll down to MINIMUM size and than up to MAXIMUM size. 
Because if the asker only scroll one down and one up that won't fix the space problem.

Answer (score 1):

Still happening in latest Windows 11:

[image: Windows 11 Explorer Extra Large view big gaps]

Ctrl + scrolling down to minimum icon size and then back again to maximum size does nothing. 99% results in Google are about changing the space between Icons in the Desktop, which has nothing to do with this, or changing the gap between lines in Explorer's left panel using 'Compact View', which also has nothing to do with this...

What I found is that it does have to do with DPI scaling. At 225% in 2160p this happens, but reseting to 100% at 2160p makes the space normal again. And then you better have an eagle level sight to use Windows.

Any further help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SU. Is this an answer to the question, or do you have an issue? If the former, please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1778243/edit) the question, remove everything that's not an answer ("FIVE years blah blah etc.) and state clearly how the OP can resolve the issue. If the latter, please [ask a question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). As you're new, check the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour), Asking and Answering in [Help](https://superuser.com/help) and older questions with accepted answers to learn how SE differs from discussion forums.

Comment: It's not a definitive solution, but it helps pointing out it comes from the DPI setting. Reducing the DPI 'solves' the problem...     but creates another problem.