# How to reduce icon spacing on folders when using a 4k screen on a WIN10

Tags: windows-registry, high-dpi

I'm using a 4k screen and icons on every folder look way too spaced. It is painful particularly when browsing pictures, since you can only see a few photos at a time, while the spacing in between is huge. See screenshots of this issue on this [related unanswered question](https://superuser.com/questions/1314775/how-to-reduce-large-icon-spacing-in-file-browser-for-windows-10).

I was able to solve this issue for the [desktop icons](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16941-change-desktop-icon-spacing-windows-10-a.html), but I cannot find a similar registry key for the folders. It must be possible to acomplish. Many programs, when running the **Open File > Folders...** the icon spacing looks ok.

Comment: Use Medium Icons instead of Tiles. That puts more content on the screen.

Comment: Medium icons are too small when browsing photos, and they are too spaced too.

Comment: Fair enough but I tested my own Windows 10 VM and spacing decreased so I am not sure about your machine.

Comment: On my machine the space is double the icon size (200%). Normal spacing is like 10% of the icon size. Folders are usable, yet I need to resize the icons down a lot, or else see very few of them.

Answer (score 0):

The good news : In Windows 11, Explorer has a new option
called **Compact view** that reduced the space between icons.

The bad news : This option only works for the view modes of
Details, List and Small icons. I have no idea why this is so,
and hope that the option will be available in the future
to more viewing modes.

[image]

You may set it globally in *Options > Folder Options > View* :

[image]

Comment: Does this setting apply to icon viewing options?

Comment: Good question. According to my tests, it only works for Details, List and Small icons. You may use the Feedback Hub to ask that this will expand to other viewing modes.

Comment: Windows sure is alert about this bug. Since there is a registry key for the Desktop, there might be another one for the folders (shell).